# Should I expect a char** or a char* here from the caller?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I have a function which accepts a pointer to some data, along with an enum representing the type of the data (lets call it processData). processData takes the data and, depending on the enum, does stuff with it (I have simplified the types here for example sake):

```
typedef enum
{
  Integer, Double, String
} DataType;

void processData(void* data, DataType type)
{
  // Do stuff with data (not necessarily modifying it like I have here,
  // but it does requires the data to be passed by pointer, and not by value)
  if (type == Integer)
  {
    (*(int*)data)++;
  }
}
```

Excluding the fact that this example is a bit weird, my question is, would it make sense to ask the caller to pass through a char* directly and then not de-reference it in my function like the other cases, or to pass through a char** and then de-reference it on my side to get a char* and deal with it from there?

Of course, both are possible - I am just asking which would be more intuitive in this sort of situation, and maybe if there are similar situations I can be referred to for reference sake.

Comment: Reference the pointer first and then pass it. When you pass the pointer, the function will have a new dual address of the pointer.

Comment: "Do stuff with data (not necessarily modifying it like I have here" needs clarity.  When you say "data" here, are you referring to the _pointer_ `data` or the object `data` points top?  `*type` is confusing here.  Why dereference the type indicator which you say is an `enum`?

Comment: I meant to type *data - woops! And the other question regarding modifying the data isn't really the pointer of the question and I don't think it would make much of a difference if I told you exactly what I was doing

Comment: Dereferncing and performing arithmetic on a `void*` pointer is *Undefined*. You must assign (or cast) the void pointer to the type it holds before dereference or arithmetic. `void` is an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I don't think you need to pass a string as `char **` because the extra layer of abstraction is not necessary, this might be confusing. I would suggest pass other types as pointers as well.

e.g.

- Input is a string -> pass `char *`
- Input is a 16 bit value -> pass `uint16_t *` and deference it in processData

Depending on what you're doing with the string, it might make sense to pass a length as well unless you're searching for "\0" every time processData is called on a string.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing. It's consistent with scanf, for example, so I feel makes the most sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An object that deals with a string can be either a character array or a pointer. For example

```
char s[10] = "Hello";
char *p = s;
```

If you are going to pass the character array using the expression `&s` then its type will not be `char **`. The type of the expression is `char ( * )[10]`.

On the other hand, if you are going to pass the pointer using the expression `&p` then the type of the expression will be indeed `char **`.

So having one enumerator for strings you will not be able to distinguish the types `char ( * )[10]` and `char **`.

So I suggest to use expressions of the type `char *` for strings. That is you will pass arrays like the expression `s` and pointers like the expression `p`. The both expressions used as arguments have the type `char *`